# Tooltip message is not displaying well

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, jsx

I have some sort of dropdown menu, inside that each item  have a question mark icon, clicking on it I display tooltip message that describe that item. Problem is that when message is a little longer it require a horizontal scroll so user can read it all, which is bad, also its not good at all on smaller devices.

This is how it looks so far:

```
const bidStatuses = [
  {
    name: t('myAds:filters.bidStatus.values.all'),
    id: 0
  },
  {
    name: (
      <>
        <span>{t('myAds:filters.bidStatus.values.unsponsored.label')}</span>
        <Tooltip title={t('myAds:filters.bidStatus.values.unsponsored.tooltip')}>
          <QuestionCircleOutlined className={styles.bidStatusOption} />
        </Tooltip>
      </>
    ),
    id: 1
  },
  {
    name: (
      <>
        <span>{t('myAds:filters.bidStatus.values.active.label')}</span>
        <Tooltip title={t('myAds:filters.bidStatus.values.active.tooltip')}>
          <QuestionCircleOutlined className={styles.bidStatusOption} />
        </Tooltip>
      </>
    ),
    id: 2
  },
  {
    name: (
      <>
        <span>{t('myAds:filters.bidStatus.values.inactive.label')}</span>
        <Tooltip title={t('myAds:filters.bidStatus.values.inactive.tooltip')}>
          <QuestionCircleOutlined className={styles.bidStatusOption} />
        </Tooltip>
      </>
    ),
    id: 3
  }
];
```

```
.bidStatusOption {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 7px;
}
```

So, tooltip message is following this

```
<QuestionCircleOutlined className={styles.bidStatusOption} />
```

and because that is on right of the screen and as I explained earlier bigger text require horizontal scroll to be seen.

I tried like this

```
<Tooltip title={t('myAds:filters.bidStatus.values.active.tooltip')}>
           <QuestionCircleOutlined className={`${styles.bidStatusOption} tooltip-content`} />
</Tooltip>
```

Adding this

```
tooltip-content
```

and then

```
.tooltip-content {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  max-width: 200px; 
}
```

But its same.

I also tried some CSS to wrap it in 2-3 rows depend of the text size but without any success.

What I can else try?

Since I dont know how to produce this code here, I post image as example:

[image]

This is on Iphone 12 pro example

[image]

You can see that I can not see text clearly full